# PHP: Sorting inside foreach

Tags: php

How can i sort by value the following code

```
$countries = array ('Europe/Rome', 'Europe/Athens', 'America/Tijuana', 'Canada/Atlantic', 'Europe/Amsterdam');
foreach ($countries as $country => $country_offset) {
$offset = timezone_offset_get( new DateTimeZone( $country_offset ), new DateTime() );
echo $offset . '</br>';
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to sort it inside the foreach? Why don't you sort it outside?

Comment: sort _how_? what've you tried?

Comment: As @EddeAlmeida said you should sort the data before `loop`ing or using `foreach`. It will make your world (and execution times) far more simple.

Comment: @Ed de Almeida I can't. I get the value (`$offset`) inside foreach.

Comment: Okay, @Avel, I got it. I've posted a solution which will solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understood things, you need to sort the $offset values. If so, then to the following:

```
$offsets = Array();
$countries = array ('Europe/Rome', 'Europe/Athens', 'America/Tijuana', 'Canada/Atlantic', 'Europe/Amsterdam');
foreach ($countries as $country_offset) {
    $offset = timezone_offset_get( new DateTimeZone( $country_offset ), new DateTime() );
    array_push($offsets, $offset);
}
asort($offsets);
foreach($offsets as $offset) {
    echo $offset . "<br />";
}
```

As you may see, you must push each $offset obtained into a new array ($offsets, in plural) and then sort it.

Besides, your construction

```
foreach ($countries as $country => $country_offset)
```

is missing a point: $country here will be the numeric index of $countries array, which you don't use in the rest of your code. Then just forget it and work just with the elements, as in

```
foreach ($countries as $country_offset)
```

Hope it helps!

OBS: To include the key, as you asked, you could do:

```
asort($offsets);
$keys = array_keys($offsets);
foreach($keys as $key) {
    echo $offsets[$key] . $key . "<br />";
}
```

Function asort preserves the keys, so if you want the names of the zones you may do

```
asort($offsets);
$keys = array_keys($offsets);
foreach($keys as $key) {
    echo $offsets[$key] . " - " . $countries[$key] . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: I'm glad it helped, @Avel.

Comment: One more question, is it possible to push the `$offsets` together with the key?
I mean to have something like this `echo $offset . $key;`

Comment: Sorry, my bad. What i intend to say is the name of the key. 
I mean to print the relative name of the key. i.e. `Europe/Rome`.

Comment: Ah, ok! No problem! In fact, asort function preserves the order of the keys. then you just need a small change. I'll edit again.

Comment: Just perfect. Added this code to get only the name of the city and works great
`$city = preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/', $countries[$key], -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    echo $offsets[$key] . " - " . $city[1] . "<br />";`

“Thank you again for your answer and for your time. You've been very helpful. Have a good time :)